# Display date and time on top of group of chat messages?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[image]
I want to show the date and time on top of chat messages based on every group of messages' time.
I made a third view for the date and time in the RecyclerView. I tried so many times to find a proper way to view the date and time, but I can't access the thing I want.
I hope the attached sample of code below will help. Thank you.

-msg_group_container.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/containerCard"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/containerLL"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/containerDay"
                android:text="@string/todo" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

-SingleChatAdapter.kt

```
class SingleChatAdapter(private var context: Context, messageList: ArrayList<SingleChatData>?, senderRoom: String,
                        receiverRoom: String, private val incDecNum: (Boolean) -> Unit,
                        private val showChosenToolbar: (Boolean, Boolean) -> Unit):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder?>() {
    
    private var selectedShared = IsSelectedShared(context)
    private val sentNum = 1
    private val receivedNum = 2
    private val msgContainer = 3
    private val senderRoom: String
    private val receiverRoom: String
    private lateinit var messages: ArrayList<SingleChatData>
    private val itemsData: ArrayList<SelectedItemsData>?= null
    // Voice Player
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == sentNum){
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.sent_message_content, parent, false)
            SentMsgViewHolder(view)
        } else if (viewType == receivedNum){
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.received_message_content, parent, false)
            ReceivedMsgViewHolder(view)
        } else {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.msg_group_container, parent, false)
            ContainerMsgViewHolder(view)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messages.size
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val newMsg = messages[position]
        return if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid == newMsg.senderId){
            sentNum
        } else {
            receivedNum
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //
    }

    inner class SentMsgViewHolder(itemView: View): ViewHolder(itemView){
        var binding = SentMessageContentBinding.bind(itemView)
        private var onItemClick: ((data: SingleChatData, weakImage: WeakReference<ImageView>) -> Unit)?= null
        var data: SingleChatData?= null
        init {
            onItemClick.let { onItemClick ->
                data?.let { data->
                    if (onItemClick != null) {
                        onItemClick(data, WeakReference(binding.sentImg))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    inner class ReceivedMsgViewHolder(itemView: View): ViewHolder(itemView){
        var binding = ReceivedMessageContentBinding.bind(itemView)
        private var onItemClick: ((data: SingleChatData, weakImage: WeakReference<ImageView>) -> Unit)?= null
        var data: SingleChatData?= null
        init {
            onItemClick.let { onItemClick ->
                data?.let { data->
                    if (onItemClick != null) {
                        onItemClick(data, WeakReference(binding.receivedImg))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    inner class ContainerMsgViewHolder(itemView: View): ViewHolder(itemView){
        var binding = MsgGroupContainerBinding.bind(itemView)
    }
    init {
        if (messageList != null){
            this.messages = messageList
        }
        this.senderRoom = senderRoom
        this.receiverRoom = receiverRoom
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want ? What is the problem ? can you add more reference ?

Comment: @SaneenKP Ok, the attached example after edit explains the problem.
I want to show the calender date and time for group of messages like the image, just like WhatsApp.

Comment: Do you have the date in any format yet? Or is this a UI question? It is unclear where you are stuck.